# how to categorize files according to user's answer

Tags: r

I try to make it simple. I've got in my working directory "Laurent/R" csv files (never more than 5) with names that change from one experiment to the other.​
Is it possible to use for and if loops to display each file one after the other and ask for each of them: "is it a "control" file ?", or to ask for each file something like " Is " "file.name[i] " "a control file ? " and codify the answer for the next steps ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```r
label_controls <- function(my_dir)
{
  filenames <- list.files(my_dir)
  is_control <- logical(length(filenames))
  for(i in seq_along(filenames))
  {
    cat(filenames[i], "\n")
    answer <- readline("Is this a control file (Y/N)? : ")
    is_control[i] <- grepl("Y|y", answer)
    cat("\n")
  }
  data.frame(filenames, is_control)
}
```

If you run this function with a particular directory, it will prompt you for each file whether it is a control file or not, to which you answer Y or N. It will return a data frame of all the files in the directory in one column, with a second column indicating whether that file is a control file or not:

```
df <- label_controls("Me/Subdir/files")

my_csv1.csv
Is this a control file (Y/N)? : N

my_csv2.csv
Is this a control file (Y/N)? : Y

my_csv3.csv
Is this a control file (Y/N)? : N
```

And you can review the results:

```
df
#>         filenames is_control
#> 1     my_csv1.csv      FALSE
#> 2     my_csv2.csv       TRUE
#> 3     my_csv3.csv      FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks Allan, it really does what i need !

Comment: @Laurent that's great. Please consider marking the answer as accepted using the green tick on the side to help other users with similar problems to find the solution.